# I'm trying to exit while loop (while also using a for loop) in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, exit, do-while

I am working on a project in which I must calculate mortgage. It's supposed to have a loan selection menu in which 1) uses default values to calculate the mortgage. 2) will allow the user to enter in custom values. 3) allows the user to exit the program and have the calculated values displayed. I have a for loop to allow the program to run up to 10 times (it can be less though). I'm currently using a do-while loop to exit the program when 3 is the selection. However it's not exiting. I"m not sure what is wrong and am hoping for an explanation and some tweaks I could implement to ensure it does what it's supposed to.

```
        do
        {
            int selection = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<loanArray.length; i++)
            {   
                System.out.println("Please choose from the following choices below: ");
                System.out.println("\t1) Promotional Loan (preset loan amount, rate, term)");
                System.out.println("\t2) Unique Loan (enter in loan values)");
                System.out.println("\t3) Quit (Exit the program)");

                System.out.println("Please enter your selection(1-3): ");
                selection = s.nextInt();

                if(selection ==1)
                {
                    loanArray[i] = new Mortgage();
                    System.out.println(loanArray[i].toString());
                }
                else if (selection ==2)
                {
                    loanArray[i].storeLoanAmount();
                    loanArray[i].storeInterestRate();
                    loanArray[i].storeTerm();
                    System.out.println(loanArray[i].toString());
                }
                else if(selection == 3)
                {
                    programSelection = false;
                    programRunning = false;
                }
            }//end of for array loop
        }while (programSelection == true);  //end of selection while loop

        System.out.println("Exit Test");    //print statement to test if selection screen exited
```

Comment: Actual comparision code looks like.  "selection" is probably not being set to 3. 
Can you please provide the sourcecode for declaration of "s"?

Also, just after ``selection = s.nextInt();`` print out the value of ``selection`` so you can check what value ``selection`` actually has.

``System.out.println("Selection=="+selection)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't actually tested this, but I think the problem is exiting the `for` loop.  The quickest way to test that is just to use a `break` statement with a label.

```
    outerLoop:
    do
    // ...
            else if(selection == 3)
            {
                break outerLoop;
            }
        }//end of for array loop
    }while (programSelection == true);  //end of selection while loop
```

Break statements with labels are discussed in the [Java tutorial.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `break;` after the `programRunning = false;`

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped my problem. I didn't realize I could use break within a do-while loop (never discussed in class).

Comment: Well, the break in this case exists just the for-loop. The do-while loop is left because you changed `programSelection` to `false` before. You can leave all kinds of loops and also `switch` branches with the `break` statement. You could even leave the outer loop if you give it a label and use that label with the break statement. Then you could completely spare the `programSelection` variable.

Answer (score 0):

you have got the correct the logic the reason is the for loop.

```
while (programSelection == true)
```

will only be executed after the for loop. Need to be cautious as well because if the `loanArray` length is 1 you might think the code works well,actually it doesnt.